# ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'newtest' | (In terminal)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import MySQL database in terminal. but I am getting same error again.

mysql -u root -p newtest < /var/www/html/WebApp/dumptest.sql

Enter password:

after entering the password, I am getting this error

ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'newtest'

anyone has idea to fix this?

Comment: Create database called newtest first.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following query to create the database with the name newtest:

```
CREATE DATABASE newtest;
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
mysql -u root -pnewtest < /var/www/html/WebApp/dumptest.sql
```

It can be found that - p and password are connected together, and there is no space between them

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).